# Why is DeLorean cold upon arrival to a destination time?

Tags: back-to-the-future

What makes the time machine drop its surface temperature once it arrives to a destination time? Why is it so cold? Shouldn't it be all hot instead due to a 1.21 gigawatt energy influx?

Comment: Given the inventor of the device (Doc. Brown) was surprised at it (if he was expecting it, he probably would not have rushed up to the car and grabbed the door handle, giving himself cold burns) it would seem there is no in-universe answer.

Comment: Note that the missing heat is apparently left behind, and that's why the car keeps setting fire to things when they depart.  So at least there's a sort of conservation of energy thing happening - to the (limited!) extent that makes any sense in this context.

Comment: As for 1.21 gigawatts, keep in mind this is a measure of power, not energy, and as far as we know we don't know how much energy is used.  For example, if the flux capacitor uses 1.21 gigawatts for one nanosecond, the actual energy consumption is only one Joule, which is negligible.

Comment: It's not a gigawatt, it's a jigawatt, which is much higher obviously.

Comment: @Broklynite a Jigawatt could be a mispronounciation of "gigawatt"

Comment: Well then, I may consider that there is no answer, because the question the moderators redirect me to has an answer to why ice is formed only in some occasions, but it doesn't answer why the DeLorean is cold in the first place. And that's what I was asking.

Comment: @Highstaker it's a joke dude

Comment: http://youtu.be/xECUrlnXCqk